# Slide down on pure css image

Tags: html, css, animation, yui-pure-css

I would like to make an animation on my menu, instead of the fade animation that you can see on the fist two div, I would like to put as animation a slide down color. As a curtain.

On hover on the image, a "coloured panel" positioned on the image slide down on it.
This is my menu:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);  /* <-- Just for the demo, Yes I like pretty fonts... */

.square {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom : 30%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
    margin: 0;//1.66%;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover; /* you change this to "contain" if you don't want the images to be cropped */
}

.img_1-1{background-image:url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg');}
.img_1-2{background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg');}
.img_1-3{background-image:url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg');}

.img_2-1{background-image:url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg');}
.img_2-2{background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg');}
.img_2-3{background-image:url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg');}

.img_3-1{background-image:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8429/7862595906_8f953fd25b.jpg');}
.img_3-2{background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg');}
.img_3-3{background-image:url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg');}




/*  following just for the demo */


body {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: 'Lato',verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:#ECECEC;
}

#bottom {
    clear:both;
    margin:0 0;//1.66%;
    width:89.68%;
    padding: 0;//3.5%;
    background-color:#1E1E1E;
    color: #fff;
}
#bottom p{
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2em;
}
#bottom a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px 20px 12px;
    line-height:70px;
    background:#ccc;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}



.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   
   }

   .fade:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
      } */
```

```html
<div  class="square img_1-1 fade">
</div>

<div class="square img_1-2 fade">
</div>
<div class="square img_1-3 ">
</div>


<div class="square img_2-1 ">
</div>
<div class="square img_2-2 ">
</div>
<div class="square img_2-3 ">
</div>


<div class="square img_3-1 ">
</div>
<div class="square img_3-2 ">
</div>
<div class="square img_3-3 ">
</div>
```

This is the animation, but I can't figure out how to do this ON the image, just by hover. 
http://jsfiddle.net/gregmatys/4x9Tf/light/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want the image to act just like the pink curtain? or you want the pink curtain to be over the image?

Comment: You can achieve what I *think* you want to using this css rule: `#wrap:hover > #slider { max-height:0; }` ?...

Comment: Ne1410s I already tried but doesn't work! I don't understand were I am wrong.

Comment: Mi-Creativity, yes! I would like the pink curtain to be over the image. Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to put the image element right inside the `#wrap` div and right before the `#slide` div, then give the `#wrap` div a `position:relative`, this is necessary because we need to absolutely position `position:absolute` the `#slider` div and give position it to `top 0` and `left:0` so that it will be above the image and cover it.

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9vx8vu7p/2/), add below code to `#wrap` and `#slider`:

**CSS:**

```
#wrap {
  position: relative;
}
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

And change your `div#wrap` structure into this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="//placehold.it/200x200?text=IMG">
  <div id="slider">
    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep! Like this! Now I just need to put this together to the other stuff. Thanks!